# Magento 2: colorbox jquery not working

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I am working on magento 2 and i want to open popup in my product detail page. But i have found problem with jquery issue and its not come every time.

Here is my `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            jQuerylib: 'Magento_Catalog/js/jquery-1.12.5.min',
            colorbox: 'Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.colorbox-min',
        }
    }
};
```

And my js function on wrapper.phtml

```
requirejs(['jquery','domReady!','colorbox'], function(jQuery){

    jQuery( ".scustomization a" ).click(function() {

        jQuery.colorbox({
                width: "90%",
                height: "90%",
                iframe: true,
                href: _url + coString,
                opacity: 0.6,
                escKey: false,
                overlayClose: false,
                onComplete: function() {
                        var theframe = jQuery('#colorbox').find('iframe')[0];
                        theframe.src = _url + coString + "&t=" + d.getTime();
                }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

I have error like bellow
[image]

Comment: I am creating custom theme  and location  custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone is still getting their heads around how to get 3rd party scripts into Magento 2, but when I needed to get Colorbox into a recent project I had to wrap the file in a `require` statement. Inside the `colorbox.js` file:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {

...the default file content...

});
```

From what I understand, you should be able to use a `shim` in your `requirejs-config.js` which would be the require's way of wrapping up the colorbox file, but when I tried to use that solution, it didn't work.