# Magento 2x child theme js error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I have created child theme for magento 2x and it's parent theme is porto theme. After create child theme everthing is working fine but sometime I have got the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ui is undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: owl.owlCarousel is not a function 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined
```

I am not sure why I am getting these error randomly. I have also tried ->  [Why is js breaking with requirejs in templates on Magento 2 and how to fix?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156523/why-is-js-breaking-with-requirejs-in-templates-on-magento-2-and-how-to-fix/) but not working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a **requirejs-config.js** in the root of the child theme

`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child` and put in the following:

```
var config = {
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }, 
        'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
        'js/jquery.stellar.min': 
            {
            deps: ['jquery']
            },
        'js/jquery.parallax.min':
            {
            deps: ['jquery']
            }
    }
};
```

And change the entries:

```
<script src="jquery.js" />
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<script src="fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js" />
```

To:

```
<remove src="jquery.js" />
<remove src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<remove src="fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js" />
```

Within file:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

No more need for merging javascripts, no more javascript errors! I have no need for the fancybox, turned it off, but if you do require it, I guess it should be included in the requirejs as well.